# Python, CherryPy, Windows Service, and BackgroundTask - Tasks not recurring as expected

Tags: python, windows, service, background, cherrypy

I am trying to get a series of python scripts to update every 60 seconds and serve JSON via CherryPy all on Windows (for WMI capabilities) and managed as a Windows Service. In short, if I run the code in a console outside the service, the tasks execute from the BackgroundTask class regularly and without problems. Once wrapped up in the CherryPy windows service, they execute once or twice, and stop working after that (the JSON stops changing).

This is CherryPy 3.3.0 on ActiveState Python 2.7 (community).

Running the code below, the script works (import snmp is the python script to be run every 60 seconds, which it does in this form).

```
import cherrypy
from cherrypy.lib.static import serve_file
import cherrypy.process.plugins
import win32serviceutil
import win32service
import win32event
import os
import snmp

class myserver():
    @cherrypy.expose
    def snmp_ajax(self):
        cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
        return snmp.json

def snmp_callback():
    global snmp_data
    snmp.generate_json(snmp_data)

snmp_data = cherrypy.process.plugins.BackgroundTask (60, snmp_callback)
snmp_data.start()

cherrypy.tree.mount(myserver(), '/', config=CONFIG)
cherrypy.config.update({
        'global':{
            'server.socket_host': '0.0.0.0',
            'server.socket_port': 8989,
        'log.screen': False,
            'engine.autoreload.on': False,
            'engine.SIGHUP': None,
            'engine.SIGTERM': None
        }                
    }) 

cherrypy.engine.start()
```

Now, to run that as a Windows Service, the bottom cherrypy code is simply put inside the CherryPyService class as follows:

```
class CherryPyService(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    """NT Service."""

    _svc_name_ = "MyService"
    _svc_display_name_ = "My Service"

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        cherrypy.tree.mount(myserver(), '/', config=CONFIG)         
        cherrypy.config.update({
                'global':{
                    'server.socket_host': '0.0.0.0',
                    'server.socket_port': 8989,
                    'log.screen': False,
                    'engine.autoreload.on': False,
                    'engine.SIGHUP': None,
                    'engine.SIGTERM': None
                }                
            }) 
        cherrypy.engine.start() 
        cherrypy.engine.block()

    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        cherrypy.engine.exit()

        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOPPED)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(CherryPyService)
```

However, once it's wrapped in the CherryPyService class, the BackgroundTask seems to stop working, it sticks on the last query and stops updating with no logic behind it. Sometimes after one run, sometimes after three, but never reaches five runs.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you adding the binding of the plugin on the SvcDoRun method? The code that you paste is not binding/subscribing the background task to the cherrypy engine, just mounting the root application.

Comment: Sorry, yes I was. It seemed to be an issue that could not be overcome, and have since moved back to Linux and Daemonizer which works perfectly.